# How to compile WSO2 WFS PHP 2.1.0 or where to get latest binaries

Tags: php, build, wso2, wsh

I'm having trouble compiling the WSO PHP framework on Windows. The latest version is here on github https://github.com/wso2/wsf.  I've been trying to follow the instructions located at /php/README.INSTALL_WIN32

The problem is that the folder structure in github does not match what that build.bat is expecting and the build fails.

I'm having to do this as part of a website running an old version of php is being upgraded to 5.3 and still needs WSF to run.

I can't find the binaries anywhere pre compiled - if someone knows where they are then that would save having to try compiling them. If not, any help in the compile process is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem as you except when trying to compile under Linux, I found the solution to be first configure/compiling the C components from the source from [here](http://wso2.com/products/web-services-framework/c/), copying the contents after make into a new folder 'wsf_c' inside the php fodler and then using the build script within the php folder of the sources from Github. I know you've likely found a way around this already but I hope this may help someone.